# What is the correct order for Hamapil?

Tags: hamapil

I am looking for any sources (preferably Ashkenaz) on how to say Hamapil/Shma Al Hamita. What I mean is: in many siddurim/cards I see the Bracha first and Shema right after. I’ve also heard to say the Bracha last is the best approach. I am specifically looking for sources on these two questions:

1. Where does the Bracha go: before or after Shema?
2. Where does Tehillim 91 go? At the end or before the Bracha?

Thank you!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8651/when-to-say-hamapil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mishna Berura 239:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.239.2?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en);

> ומברך המפיל וכו' - מלשון השו"ע משמע דברכת המפיל אומר אחר ק"ש כדי שתהא הברכה סמוכה לשינה ומה שקורא אח"כ יושב בסתר ואינך כיון דהוי משום שמירה לא הוי הפסק [ויש מדקדקין לברך המפיל בסוף אחר כל הפסוקים] ויש מאחרונים שהסכימו שיברך ברכת המפיל קודם ואח"כ ק"ש ויתר פסוקי דרחמי (כמו שנדפס בסידורים) ונראה דלמעשה יתנהג האדם כפי טבעו דהיינו אם טבעו להרדם באמצע ק"ש טוב יותר שיקדים ברכת המפיל מה דאפשר ואם אין טבעו לזה טוב יותר לאחר ברכת המפיל עד לבסוף:

The Sefardi Minhag is to say it before (Yalkut Yosef (Brachot pg 667))